# Conversion from Wei to Ether gives different results

Tags: transactions, ether, web3.py, polygon, sidechain

I'm trying to analyze the transaction of [this contract](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x95f57249e6dd394318025068a8bfc841ac6ec0dd), but sometimes when I try to convert from wei to ether value of tokens I got comma in different position than expected. This is how I proceed:

1)Fetch all transactions from Moralis API. 
2)Take the ABI of the contract, and from the tx_input I decode the transaction in this way:

```
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(tx["to_address"]), abi=abi['result'])
func_obj, func_params = contract.decode_function_input(tx["input"])
```

3. I get the wei value of token sent to the contract selecting the `func_params` with the following path `func_params['amountsInOutMarketMaxFee'][0]` in the case of `Swap Function` invoked.

Everything is fine unless in some case when I try to convert some numbers from wei to ether value I got different numbers than seen in explorers. For example when I fetch the following transaction from the contract above:
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xea4e56d19226aa07dcacc70a015c38c674644476fb99a9b4365195b415d16768
I got the following value:

```
20000000000000000000
```

That's the same amount you get from the decoded input in the blockchain explorer page.
But if I try to convert the amount with the following function:

```
 Web3.fromWei(tx_data['amountsInOutMaxFee'][0], 'ether')
```

I got 2.0 while on the blockchain explorer the amount is 20.0
Why is there this lack? Thank you for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though something else is going wrong which is not really easy to tell from what you posted. If you believed the function itself (conversion) was wrong we can plug in the number you see on the block explorer to check it:

```
>>> Web3.fromWei(20000000000000000000, 'ether')
Decimal('20')
```

So, the conversion is not wrong. I went ahead and pulled the exact same code you posted above and this is the result:

```
In [9]: func_obj, func_params = contract.decode_function_input(tx["input"])

In [10]: func_params
Out[10]: 
{'tokenInOutMarket': ['0x282d8efCe846A88B159800bd4130ad77443Fa1A1',
'0xF807cA842d8fB217FCF0a0DF8e84e447358C6e86',
'0x9984b2453eC7D99a73A5B3a46Da81f197B753C8d'],
'amountsInOutMaxFee': [20000000000000000000,
14490815500000000000,
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639934,
0]}

In [11]: func_params['amountsInOutMaxFee'][0]
Out[11]: 20000000000000000000

In [12]: Web3.fromWei(func_params['amountsInOutMaxFee'][0], 'ether')
Out[12]: Decimal('20')
```

Not sure what else to tell you but it seems like this isn't reproducible. Best of luck.